# Converting iOS9 coalesced touches drawing code for iOS8 and iOS7 compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, drawing

I have the below code from a project available at: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/SmoothScribble/tree/master/SmoothScribble

Currently this project only runs on iOS9 as the project uses `UIStackView` and `coalescedTouchesForTouch` which are only available for iOS9. However I wish to convert the project to make it available for iOS7 and iOS8 as well. How do I go about doing that?

I think I might have a handle on how I might go about replacing `UIStackView` with a `UIView`. However, how do I handle sections that refer to `coalescedTouches`?

For instance, how do I convert the below code snippet so that it conforms to a traditional `touchesMoved` that works on iOS8 and iOS9?

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
guard let
    touch = touches.first,
    coalescedTouches = event?.coalescedTouchesForTouch(touch),
    touchOrigin = touchOrigin
    else
{
    return
}

coalescedTouches.forEach
    {
        hermiteScribbleView.appendScribble($0.locationInView(touchOrigin))
        simpleScribbleView.appendScribble($0.locationInView(touchOrigin))
}
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
let stackView = UIStackView()

let hermiteScribbleView = HermiteScribbleView(title: "Hermite")
let simpleScribbleView = SimpleScribbleView(title: "Simple")

var touchOrigin: ScribbleView?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(hermiteScribbleView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(simpleScribbleView)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    guard let
        location = touches.first?.locationInView(self.view) else
    {
        return
    }

    if(hermiteScribbleView.frame.contains(location))
    {
        touchOrigin = hermiteScribbleView
    }
    else if (simpleScribbleView.frame.contains(location))
    {
        touchOrigin = simpleScribbleView
    }
    else
    {
        touchOrigin = nil
        return
    }

    if let adjustedLocationInView = touches.first?.locationInView(touchOrigin)
    {
        hermiteScribbleView.beginScribble(adjustedLocationInView)
        simpleScribbleView.beginScribble(adjustedLocationInView)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    guard let
        touch = touches.first,
        coalescedTouches = event?.coalescedTouchesForTouch(touch),
        touchOrigin = touchOrigin
        else
    {
        return
    }

    coalescedTouches.forEach
        {
            hermiteScribbleView.appendScribble($0.locationInView(touchOrigin))
            simpleScribbleView.appendScribble($0.locationInView(touchOrigin))
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    hermiteScribbleView.endScribble()
    simpleScribbleView.endScribble()
}

override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    if motion == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake
    {
        hermiteScribbleView.clearScribble()
        simpleScribbleView.clearScribble()
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
        y: topLayoutGuide.length,
        width: view.frame.width,
        height: view.frame.height - topLayoutGuide.length).insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10)

    stackView.axis = view.frame.width > view.frame.height
        ? UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal
        : UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical

    stackView.spacing = 10

    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
}
}
```

Full project code available at: project available at: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/SmoothScribble/tree/master/SmoothScribble

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I also had a question on compatibility and it turned out that it could be solved easily by **Availability Condition**, like this:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
  let store = CNContactStore()
} else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

You can read this article to know more about it.
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/checking-api-availability-with-swift.html

I do not know if we have the same problem. But, in my view, I could have two snippets of code comforming to iOS 9 and iOS 8 respectively, and use **Availability Condition** or **@available Attribute** to resolve compatibility problem.